# Why can't I set the value of a json property using Jayway JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a requirement where I need to update a value in JSON. The path of the key which I need to update is also based on some condition so I have to maintain path in property file.
This is my JSON

```
String jsonString = "{\"delivery_codes\": [{\"postal_code\": {\"district\": \"District1\", \"pin\": 201001, \"pre_paid\": \"Y\", \"cash\": \"Y\", \"pickup\": \"Y\", \"repl\": \"N\", \"cod\": \"Y\", \"is_oda\": \"N\", \"sort_code\": \"GB\", \"state_code\": \"UP\"}}]}";
```

Now my requirement is Suppose I need to update value of pre_paid to N but need the path of pre_paid to be dynamically because it may be possible that sometime I need to update state_code or sort_code or pre_paid etc.
So I used JSONPath:

```
String jsonPathExpressionForDistrict = "$['delivery_codes'][0]['postal_code']['district']";
String jsonPathExpressionForState_code = "$['delivery_codes'][0]['postal_code']['state_code']";
```

These paths i need to store in some properties file/DB.

I am able to read the property by below code:

```
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).read(jsonPathExpressionForDistrict , JsonNode.class) -> This gives me value 'District1'
```

But when I am trying to update the value with below code:

```
JsonPath.parse(jsonString).put(jsonPathExpressionForDistrict , "District2", String.class);
```

This gives me below error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidModificationException: Can only add
>   properties to a map
>         at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.PathRef$ObjectPropertyPathRef.put(PathRef.java:265)
>         at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.put(JsonPath.java:304)
>         at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.put(JsonContext.java:221)
>         at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.put(JsonContext.java:199)
>         at com..service.ServiceImpl.main(ServiceImpl.java:179)

Someone please guide me on this.

Comment: Maybe format your json so that it is readable?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late but maybe this can help someone else.
The OP got that error because value `jsonPathExpressionForDistrict` is a path to an attribute not a JSON object or a map.

To add `district2` to `postal_code`, the path should be `"$['delivery_codes'][0]['postal_code']"`.

To update/add any value in JSON by using JSonPath, we can use the way mentioned in the post, however need to check and make the path is valid in source JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to update the value of an already existing node you should use set method. I hope the snipped below helps:

```
String jsonString = "{\"delivery_codes\": [{\"postal_code\": {\"district\": \"District1\", \"pin\": 201001, \"pre_paid\": \"Y\", \"cash\": \"Y\", \"pickup\": \"Y\", \"repl\": \"N\", \"cod\": \"Y\", \"is_oda\": \"N\", \"sort_code\": \"GB\", \"state_code\": \"UP\"}}]}";

    String jsonPathExpressionForDistrict = "$['delivery_codes'][0]['postal_code']['district']";
    String jsonPathExpressionForState_code = "$['delivery_codes'][0]['postal_code']['state_code']";

    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
    System.out.println(documentContext.jsonString());

    String read = documentContext.read(jsonPathExpressionForDistrict);

    System.out.println(read);
    documentContext.set(jsonPathExpressionForState_code, "District2");

    System.out.println(documentContext.jsonString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.json library.

[Org.JSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

You can take a JSONArray and get the Keys for the Items in the array.

You can get an Item like this:

```
array.getJSONObject(i).getInt("postal_code");
```

In this case, i is the item in the JSONArray.

Good luck.

Comment: My requirement is how to give the path of the key dynamically.